# Accessibility dropdown menu

Tags: accessibility

I have the following menu and I am not be able to access the options because when I navigate through them, it immediately goes to the first link, as if I am selecting it. How can I access with the tab key the next options? I want to select the option with enter, so that it goes to the link.

```
<select role="menu" name="select-rates-jump-to-page-1" class="select js-jump-to-page">

              <option role="menuitem" value="" selected="">Select a product</option>

           <option role="menuitem" value="http://www.google.com">Rice</option>


           <option role="menuitem" value="http://yahoo.com">Chicken</option>


           <option role="menuitem" value="htpp://www.bing.com">Salad</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `<select>` menu is not really used for selecting a list of links. It's main purpose is to select an option that will be given to the sever after a form submission.

If you want a dropdown menu of links that will navigate to a page, I suggest the patterned defined in [Inclusive Components](https://inclusive-components.design/menus-menu-buttons/) for an accessible drop down menu of links.

```js
var navButton = document.querySelector('nav button');
navButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let expanded = this.getAttribute('aria-expanded') === 'true' || false;
  this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', !expanded);
  let menu = this.nextElementSibling;
  menu.hidden = !menu.hidden;
});
```

```css
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
  <button aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="menu-list">Select a product</button>
  <ul id="menu-list" hidden>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Rice</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://yahoo.com">Chicken</a></li>
    <li><a href="htpp://www.bing.com">Salad</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```